# Can someone recommend a colour picker component for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, colors, components, picker

I'm looking for a (preferably free) component for Delphi for users to easily select about 100 different colours.

I've currently got one as part of DevExpress's editors, but it only has about 20 proper colours to choose, with a bunch of other 'Windows' colours like clHighlight, clBtnFace, etc.

It's for regular users, so would like to avoid requiring them to manually select RGB values.

Something similar to the colour picker in MS Paint might work, or something that lists X11/web colours:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Colors

So, please let me know if you got any recommendations.

**Thanks for the suggestions from everyone**

All of the suggestions were good, I didn't realise the MS Paint colour dialog can be called, that's all I needed and is the simplest solution. Thanks

Comment: OK a bit late... :-) I can't check right now, but I'd be surprised if one couldn't configure the DevEx picker to omit system colors and maybe show more than 20 choices.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What's wrong with the TColorDialog?
It gives you the standard Windows color dialog, exactly the same as in MSPaint...
Add these options to show it directly expanded and with all colors available.

```
object ColorDialog1: TColorDialog
  Options = [cdFullOpen, cdAnyColor]
end
```

Answer (score 13):

Delphi Gems' Color Picker control, maybe?

http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php/controls/color-picker-control

Comment: That the selected answer holds MSPaint as the standard for applications is pretty grim. This is a good alternative.

Comment: This component is no longer available from that site.

Answer (score 7):

Give mbColor Lib from MXS a go. Perhaps the most comprehensive set of color picking components for Delphi. [MXS Components](http://mxs.bergsoft.net/index.php?p=3)

Answer (score 2):

There was an article about creating a custom colour selection component in issue 3 of the blaise pascal magazine.

http://www.blaisepascal.eu/blaisepascal_3/color_selection_component_david_dirkse.php