# Recommend color picker utility with support for Delphi color codes

Tags: delphi, color-picker

I'm looking for a free color picking application with support for Delphi color codes. 
- Something like the [ColorPic](http://www.iconico.com/colorpic/) would be perfect. (ColorPic colour codes aren't compatible with Delphi)
- Support for color sets would be a bonus.

Please let me know if you have any recommendations.

[edit]
To clarify, I'm looking for a standalone color selection tool, not a component.
[/edit]

Comment: First, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279822/can-someone-recommend-a-colour-picker-component-for-delphi
Next, please be more specific about what you want your application to do. (This is a programming site, so the expectation is that you're writing this program yourself.)

Comment: I'd rather use an existing application but will program one myself if none are available. This is a programming site, but I assumed questions regarding tools to help programmers be more productive would be acceptable?

Answer (score 8):

I found [Color Cop- http://colorcop.net](http://colorcop.net/download). It has an eye dropper, allows colors to be picked and support for Delphi color codes. It doesn't support color sets.

Comment: That's a nice tool.  Thanks for the tip, I've added this to my toolkit :)

Comment: Great! Except that switching to Delphi color hex color output mode is not overly obvious.

Answer (score 5):

[Already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279822/can-someone-recommend-a-colour-picker-component-for-delphi).

This looks like a nice one: [image: ColorLib]
<sub>(source: [bergsoft.net](http://mxs.bergsoft.net/images/logocolorlib.png))</sub>

> [ColorLib](http://mxs.bergsoft.net/index.php?p=3) is the most complete color picker and conversion library you can find for Delphi. These components provide you with professional ways to pick colors and convert between color models as well as HTML color conversion utilities. In the newest release this pack contains 31 color tools which can be combined, letting you create numerous new tools and color dialogs. It integrates with XP Lib (optional) to provide a complete MS Office - style color dialog. So, will your users still be picking colors using TColorDialog?

[image]
<sub>(source: [bergsoft.net](http://mxs.bergsoft.net/images/colorlib.png))</sub>