# Is there a color map control in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, colors, controls, delphi-7, delphi-xe2

First of all, I just installed XE2 for the first time, and plan to work here, as well as Delphi 7. Is there a control which displays a color map to pick from, like the one in the color dialog? Just a simple control with all colors to pick from, like these:

[image]
[image]

Anything like that already in Delphi XE2 and/or 7? Doesn't need to be exactly like the pictures, in fact it needs to cover all the colors possible. If not, where can I get one?

Comment: related or duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279822/can-someone-recommend-a-colour-picker-component-for-delphi

Comment: Related, but not duplicate - other question is asking for more generally anything to let user pick over 100 colors, whereas I'm looking for a single control which supports many color pallets. Other q was answered by use of the color dialog, I'm trying to avoid the dialog.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the [`Color Lib`](http://mxs.bergsoft.net/index.php?p=2) Library, is very complete and freeware I use my self on one of my [projects](http://code.google.com/p/delphi-ide-theme-editor/), the orignal version supports delphi 5,7 and 2005. if you want a Delphi XE2 version you can check the [repository](http://code.google.com/p/delphi-ide-theme-editor/source/browse/#svn/trunk/delphi-ide-theme-editor) of my project and download the file [`mbColorLib2.0.2_XE2.rar`](http://delphi-ide-theme-editor.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/delphi-ide-theme-editor/mbColorLib2.0.2_XE2.rar)

Comment: +1 very nice. I didn't even know this page of good stuff existed!

Comment: Thanks, a lot of cool things here I'll find useful with this :D

Answer (score 1):

I have had good luck with [SoftGems Color Picker](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php/controls/color-picker-control), another great free/open-source component by the same guy who made the popular virtual treeview control.

Comment: Sounds like it must be fairly stable and complete then, thanks